# How to expose a WCF Service to web using IIS

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

I'm working with WCF Service and I would like to know how to expose my WCF Service to the web using IIS.

My OS is Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bits
I have IIS 7

Right now I can use my Web service through my local network (192.168...), but if I write my ip address\MyApp\MyService I don't reach my service page. I'm able to reach my router configuration page, but not my service.

I also tried in Visual Studio by adding a "Service reference" and it can't reach the service.

I'm not sure if I gave enough information, so if you need more just ask me.

Comment: have you tried this? -> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitlale/archive/2007/05/21/hosting-wcf-service-in-iis.aspx

Comment: Configure a test Default.aspx and see if you an get to it va ip\Address\MyApp\Default.aspx

Comment: Do you have a static IP that has been mapped to your machine on which the WCF service is hosted? If so then you should be able to reach from the web without any problem by using the static ip in the address

Comment: Thanks for your answers, Ann B.: I'll check your link later. Blam: I tryed what you said, but it didn't work. Rajesh, no I don't have a static IP, but my IP change few time a year and my goal for now is just playing with wcf.

Does I need to open port on my router or firewall, add special configuration on my router?